# Does the use of 'headers' in requests.get() method's parameter change HTML code or effect it somehow?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The code below is supposed to retrieve links from the search results page of google.

Without using header `'linkedElems'` has 0 elements, but when I used a header `'linkedElems'` had 44 elements which means after using header "select('.r a')" found 44 elements in page. Does the `HTML` code of a page change when a header is used?

I inspected the page's `HTML` code using the firefox's developer tool to find links and select them so "select('.r a') isn't supposed to return 0.

***Code:***

```
import requests,bs4

print("Search something in google:")
searchKeyword = input()
print("Googling.... " + searchKeyword)

head = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0'}
responseObj = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q="+searchKeyword, headers = head)
responseObj.raise_for_status()

print("Status code: " + str(responseObj.status_code))
soupObj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(responseObj.text, features='html.parser')
linkedElems = soupObj.select('.r a')
print(len(linkedElems))
```

***Result (With header):***

```
Search something in google:
test
Googling.... test
Status code: 200
44

Process finished with exit code 0
```

***Result (Without header):***

```
Search something in google:
test
Googling.... test
Status code: 200
0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`User-Agent` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) is specifically designed for the server to know the browser/OS/hardware of the client that issued the request so it can build the proper response to that specific client:

> The User-Agent request header is a characteristic string that lets servers and network peers identify the application, operating system, vendor, and/or version of the requesting user agent.

If Google's server was designed to return a specific HTML for specific clients (spoiler alert, it was), then the answer is "yes, the HTML **will** be different for different values of User-Agent", as you discovered yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `User-Agent` in `requests.get` causes `requests` module to substitute some default `User-Agent`, and then it causes Google to return a much simpler page to you, and it probably has a different structure. Without `User-Agent` I'm getting a response with the length of 30328, with -- 219287.

You can see the difference by doing something like

```
with open("temp.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(responseObj.text)
```

and then opening the `temp.html` file in a browser.

Comment: FWIW the `User-Agent` is not missing from the request. `requests` is using a  default value of `'python-requests/2.22.0'`

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course. I'll edit the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem as other answers are mentioned about `user-agent` is that [default `requests` `user-agent` is python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) thus Google understands that it's a request made by bot/script and you received a different HTML with some sort of an error that doesn't contain `.r a` `CSS` selector. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

---

You can forget about such a problem by using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't have to maintain the code, figure out how to bypass blocks from Google and other search engines, or figure out how to extract something from Javascript since it's already done for the end user.

Example code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",    # search engine
  "q": "tesla",          # query
  "hl": "en",            # language
  "gl": "us",            # country to search from
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# scrapes all organic results (in this case, from the first page)
for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['title'])
  print(result['link'])
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.